# How to bind arrays in a variable in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, bind-variables

How to bind arrays in a variable in `PL/SQL`.

For Example i have below array:

```
array_col3 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

now i want to `select` from a table based on the `array`.

```
select * from tabA where col3 in (select * from (:array_col3));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array in IN() clause oracle PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515772/array-in-in-clause-oracle-plsql)

Comment: It appears you are defining the array in some language other than PL/SQL and want to pass it as a bind variable. If that is the case you need to use dynamic SQL. [This other SO thread has the solution you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8969591/146325).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this below snippet helps.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv sys.odcivarchar2list:=sys.odcivarchar2list('1','2','3','4');
  lv1 sys.odcivarchar2list;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv1
  FROM
    ( SELECT LEVEL LVL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10
    )A
  WHERE A.lvl IN
    (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(LV)
    ) ;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv1.COUNT);
END;

###############################OUTPUT##########################################

anonymous block completed
4

###############################OUTPUT##########################################
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [`table()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2065746) expression:

```
select * from tabA where col3 in (select * from table((:array_col3)));
```

or alternatively the [`member of`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52135) operator:

```
select * from tabA where col3 member of :array_col3;
```

Answer (score 0):

In plsql its not so simple. You have to use types, have a look at dbms_utility package .

Example:

```
Va dbms_utility.number_array;
 Va(1) := 1;
 Va(2) := 2;
```

Comment: This is not what @Abhi85 has asked for.

Comment: Hmmm, he asked: How to bind arrays in a variable in PL/SQL. But your answer looks more complete.