# SQL Dynamic binding in a IN list

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

## Curent situation

Currently I have this PL-SQL script with almost fifty words "hard-coded":

```
DECLARE
categoryToSearch VARCHAR2(16);
BEGIN
categoryToSearch := 'my_category';
FOR my_object IN (SELECT my_field FROM my_schema.my_table
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN ('WORD_1', 'WORD_2', 'WORD_3', 'WORD_4', 'WORD_5', 'WORD_6')
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field)
LOOP
    -- <loop code>
END LOOP;
-- <code>
```

This is working (yes I only display 6 words for the example)

## What I want

But now I would like to change dynamically this list of words, so I implemented the following:

```
DECLARE
categoryToSearch VARCHAR2(16);
listOfWords      VARCHAR2(512);
BEGIN
categoryToSearch := 'my_category';
listOfWords      := '''WORD_1'', ''WORD_2'', ''WORD_3'', ''WORD_4'', ''WORD_5'', ''WORD_6''';
FOR my_object IN (SELECT my_field FROM my_schema.my_table
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN ( listOfWords )        -- I changed this, putting a variable instead of a hard-coded list
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field)
LOOP
    -- <loop code>
END LOOP;
-- <code>
```

This "compiles" (ho ho ho), I mean no SQL errors. But strange issue, this code do NOT return any rows compare to the first one, like `listOfWord` became empty, different or badly interpreted, I don't know why.

## Questions:

- Why my new version is not working ?
- Why it is working with `categoryToSearch` and NOT with `listOfWords` ?
- When using `IN ( listOfWord )`, could it be any issue with the quotes ? (=> assignment)
- Am I doing correctly the binding ? (eg. using `:` or `@` ?)
- Can I use a `USING` to bind ? i try but nothing work

## I tried:

```
FOR my_object IN (SELECT my_column FROM schemaToAnalyze
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN ( :my_list )
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field) USING listOfWords
```

even

```
FOR my_object IN ('SELECT my_column FROM schemaToAnalyze
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN (' || listOfWords || ')
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field')
```

and

```
FOR my_object IN (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT my_column FROM schemaToAnalyze
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN (' || listOfWords || ')
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field')
```

and even:

```
FOR my_object IN (SELECT my_column FROM schemaToAnalyze
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN ( @listOfWords )
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field)
```

Comment: The first PL/SQL block you posted does not work.  You are selecting `my_column` but grouping by `my_field`, so you will get a `not a GROUP BY expression` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check for a IN condition against a dynamic list in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462011/how-do-i-check-for-a-in-condition-against-a-dynamic-list-in-oracle)

Comment: @LukeWoodward : Thanks spotting that error, i change it

Comment: `FROM schemaToAnalyze` also won't work in your original version, unless you're using dynamic SQL - which you haven't shown. Anyway, collections are the answer, as shown in the linked question.

Comment: @Gary_W : I tried the collection, but I cannot perform any "create or replace" since our DBA does not allow it. Or is there any other way to create a temp table with few rights ?

Comment: @AlexPoole : the exact query is:
`SELECT table_name FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE table_owner = aSchemaName AND table_owner NOT LIKE '%_T' AND table_name IN ( SELECT table_name FROM all_tab_partitions WHERE table_name IN (aTablesToProcessText) ) GROUP BY table_name ORDER BY table_name` and indeed the variable is aSchemaName not for the name of the table. I thought it will be the same, so I will change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried the collection, but I cannot perform any "create or replace" since our DBA does not allow it.

You can use a built-in collection type, such as [odcivarchar2list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/extensibility-constants-types-and-mappings.html#GUID-4DC91855-BEF3-4D27-827E-147C74F127A2):

```
DECLARE
schemaToAnalyze  VARCHAR2(16);
categoryToSearch VARCHAR2(16);
listOfWords      SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
categoryToSearch := 'my_category';
--schemaToAnalyze  := 'my_schema.my_table';
listOfWords      := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('WORD_1', 'WORD_2', 'WORD_3', 'WORD_4', 'WORD_5', 'WORD_6');
FOR my_object IN (SELECT my_field FROM my_table -- schemaToAnalyze
                  WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
                  AND my_field IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE(listOfWords) )
                  GROUP BY my_field ORDER BY my_field)
LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(my_object.my_field);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=78818b1d73bd15289b667885213b16e4)

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce the second attempt, which has variable concatenation, through use of `SYS_REFCURSOR` while keeping the current local variable (`listOfWords`) within a stored function or procedure such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fn_Analyze_Schema RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR; 
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  listOfWords VARCHAR2(32767) := '''WORD_1'',''WORD_2'',''WORD_3'',....';
BEGIN
  v_sql := 'SELECT my_column 
              FROM schemaToAnalyze
             WHERE other_field = categoryToSearch
               AND my_field IN ('||listOfWords||')
             GROUP BY my_field 
             ORDER BY my_field';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

Then call the following code from *SQL Developer*'s command line

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Fn_Analyze_Schema;
PRINT rc
```

Comment: Maybe it is solution that way works, but I do not have rights to test it:

Comment: `Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges`

Comment: Hi @user12642493 , the message seems explanatory that just consult your DBA, most probably ask h[er|im] to grant you  `create function` privilege.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to remove the double claws on your variable assignment listOfwords

Comment: I tried this:
`listOfWords := 'WORD_1, WORD_2, WORD_3, WORD_4, WORD_5, WORD_6';`
Didn't worked (same, the query returns nothing)

Comment: Either way you're trying to match a single string, which happens to contain commas, not a set of individual strings. The `IN (listOfWords)` is the same as `= listOfWords`.